# Acumatica: Getting value of field on header from grid change event

Tags: acumatica

I think I've got a fairly simple problem, but I'm new to Acumatica. I'd like a custom field on the header of the sales order (SO.30.10.00) to to have some effect on the price of items on the grid. As such, I need 2 things.

1) I need the grid to read a value from the header. I took a look at another similar request but I can't seem to make it work. On the SO, it looks like this code should read the value of the current order number, but I get "The name 'Document' does not exist in the current context"

```
string TestString = Document.Current.OrderNbr;
```

2) Would it be possible to have all the line recalculate when that field changes? I actually think that's probably the easy part, but since I'm asking the first part I figured I toss that out here too.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operation flows from Header Field to the Grid Rows Field. When header field is modified then update the rows. That would be #2 in your question.

In #1 your issue is that Documents data view is a member of SOOrderEntry **graph** not a member of the SOOrderEntry **graph extension** you created. In **graph extension** context you access base graph properties using `Base` property so you would be looking at `Base.Document`.

For implementation, first you want the header field to raise events when it's modified. This is accomplished by setting the ASPX control `CommitChanges` property to `true`:

[image]

Next you want to declare a `FieldUpdated` event handler to hook header field modification and modify details lines based on header field:

```
using PX.Data;

namespace PX.Objects.SO
{
    public class SOOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
    {
        public void SOOrder_OrderDesc_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            SOOrder order = e.Row as SOOrder;

            if (order != null)
            {
                foreach (SOLine line in Base.Transactions.Select())
                {
                    line.TranDesc = order.OrderDesc;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Before modifying Header field:
[image]

After modifying Header field:
[image]

I used simple `=` assignation to set the value of details line. You could use `SetValue` method or `SetValueExt` when you want assignation to raise event. Using `SetValueExt` will raise the FieldUpdated event.

Comment: If you need initialization too, you need other mechanism. FieldDefaulting could be one.

Comment: Awesome. This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Part 2 is perfect, and actually solved another issue. I'm slightly confused on part one though. I'm sure it's my own ignorance, I can use 'Base.Document.Current.OrderNbr' for example, but how do I get to a user field that I've added? For example, 'Base.Document.Current.UsrDeburr' (a user field I've added) doesn't work. I'm sure I'm not properly referring to the ext but I don't quite know how to make that work.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Base.Document.Current holds the SOOrder record and you have to fetch the extension from it to access the custom field. Assuming the extension is named SOOrderExt and for brevity sake here's how to access it as a one liner: "(Base.Document.Current.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>() as SOOrderExt).UsrDeburr" You'd want to add null checks after fetching the extension and before accesing the custom field.

Comment: Thanks **AGAIN**. I'm so, so close thanks to your help. I've got code in the FieldUpdatedEvents that now reads from the header perfectly. I can force the header to update the lines, but what I'd really like is when the "deburr" field is clicked to just force it to run the function that updates a line for each record. It's currently called from several of the usr fields (header looks like 'UpdateLine(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)'). I think something like SetValueExt might be what I'm after, but can't quite see how I make that run from the "line" loop.

Comment: For what it's worth, I tried using `sender.SetValueExt<SOLine.tranDesc>(line, "Clicked");` in place of `line.TranDesc = "Clicked"` but that seems to not update it. I'm guessing maybe I'm misunderstanding the PXCache here.

Comment: There's no Click event handler for DAC fields editor control in the BLC event framework. It can be rigged with JavaScript but goes against framework philosophy and  is not recommended. I'm missing complete info here so I'll explore a few option. If Deburr field is a checkbox and by clicking on the control it toggles Checked/Unchecked state then you should use FieldUpdated to hook that event: public void SOOrder_UsrDeburr_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e). Field updated event is not fired on click, it's fired when the control value change and the editor control lost focus.

Comment: If by click you mean that clicking doesn't change the value of Deburr field then you should use an action button. Action button are the proper way to hook click events. When you click on the button the action event handler is executed in the BLC.

Comment: I can't tell exactly why the field isn't updated without full code for context. SetValueExt shouldn't be required, it's used to trigger the FieldUpdated events of the field you change but TranDesc doesn't need that. Your saying the field is updated from many locations, are you sure it isn't updated multiple times? If from one location it works why not from the other? What's the context in which you're setting the value, from which event handler? I understand it worked from FieldUpdated like suggested in my answer.

Comment: Some debugging could be required, for example are you sure events are called? Maybe your missing CommitChanges = True on the field editor control. Without this property set to true, events handlers callback to server are not performed when you change a field value from UI.

Comment: So I think that my sample code with "clicked" in it has created some confusion! My end goal is that the final price on a SOLine is calculated by looking at a several fields on the SOLine and 2 user added fields (of which "Deburr" is one) on the header. As such, I have a function that runs whenever one significant line fields changes. What I would like to do, is when the header "Deburr" value changes, have this run for each line. I believe that using SetValueEx on one of the values that triggers the update to run would work. This would avoid having to duplicate the logic that is in the lines.

Comment: For example, one of the fields used in the calculation is usrWidth...the following works perfectly to update the end price: 
`protected void SOLine_UsrWidthAdder_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
      UpdateLine (cache, e);
    }`
which then runs this:
    `protected void UpdateLineDirect(PXCache cache, SOLine TheRow)
    {
 ...
 }`
So really I just need the header to run the above procedure for each line, but haven't worked out how I can make that happen.

Comment: To avoid duplicating logic putting the validation in a method that is called from multiple event source is enough. Add a FieldUpdated event on Deburr field (SOOrder_UsrDeburr_FieldUpdated) and set CommitChanges property to  True on the ASPX control. When Deburr value changes and control lose focus it fires the event and call the logic method. I fail to see where SetValueExt is useful in that scenario. If value assignment don't work, depending on where the logic is called from you might want to add an explicit update call on the dataview: Base.Transactions.Update(line).

Comment: I'm sure my ignorance is at fault here. I tried calling the update from the header, using the PXCache from the Deburr field update procedure, and the "line" from the loop, and while I got no errors, it didn't seem to do anything. My code looked like this:     `protected void UpdateLineDirect(PXCache cache, SOLine TheRow)
    {...update code...}` and was called from the loop you had helped me with: `  foreach (SOLine line in Base.Transactions.Select())
  {
     UpdateLineDirect(sender, line);
  }`

Comment: That got no syntax or runtime errors, but also didn't appear to update the grid.

Comment: It could be a case where you have to update the dataview. After changing the value of line, try updating the dataview with "line = Base.Transactions.Update(line);".

Comment: Oh I think you might be running into a cache mismatch error. If you use SOOrder cache when SOLine cache is expected it won't work. In my answer cache is not used but if you use it make sure it matches the operation you're doing with cache object. You can get a cache reference for SOLine from everywhere by doing "Base.Transactions.Cache" or "Base.Caches[typeof(SOLine)]"